# c++20 infinite ranges/views compiler error

Tags: c++, c++20, infinite-sequence

So I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRkJCvHWdwQ) (14:30) about the new c++ 20 features and wanted to try out infinite ranges.

I wrote this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ranges>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

bool primeCheck(const int&);

int main()
{
    auto ints = std::ranges::view::ints(0);
    auto primes {
        ints
        | std::ranges::views::filter([](const auto& value){ return primeCheck(value); })
        | std::ranges::views::take(100)
    };

    for (auto p : primes)
    {
        cout << p << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool primeCheck(const int& value)
{
    if (value <= 1) return false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= round(sqrt(value)); i++)
    {
        if (value % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However I get the following compiler output:

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j4 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ InfiniteSequences - Release ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/paul/Documents/Projects/InfiniteSequences'
/usr/bin/g++-10  -c  "/home/****/Documents/Projects/InfiniteSequences/main.cpp" -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-signedness -Wformat-y2k -Wnull-dereference -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-default -Wunused-parameter -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-attribute=const -Walloc-zero -Walloca -Wconversion -Wfloat-conversion -Wsign-conversion -Wduplicated-branches -Wduplicated-cond -Wtrampolines -Wfloat-equal -Wshadow=compatible-local -Wundef -Wunused-macros -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align=strict -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wstack-protector -fstack-protector -pedantic-errors -Werror=pedantic -Werror=char-subscripts -Werror=null-dereference -Werror=init-self -Werror=implicit-fallthrough=2 -Werror=misleading-indentation -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=multistatement-macros -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=multichar -DNDEBUG  -o ./Release/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
/home/****/Documents/Projects/InfiniteSequences/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
/home/****/Documents/Projects/InfiniteSequences/main.cpp:14:30: error: expected 'auto' or 'decltype(auto)' after 'view'
   14 |     auto ints = std::ranges::view::ints(0);
      |                              ^~~~
/home/****/Documents/Projects/InfiniteSequences/main.cpp:14:30: error: 'template<class _Tp> concept std::ranges::view' used without template arguments
make[1]: *** [InfiniteSequences.mk:95: Release/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/paul/Documents/Projects/InfiniteSequences'
make: *** [Makefile:5: All] Error 2
====2 errors, 0 warnings====
```

I looked it up again from a [different source](https://namespace-cpp.de/std/lib/exe/fetch.php/ranges_slides.pdf) (page 6) and it should work, I think.

Comment: `std::ranges::view::ints` looks odd. Did you mean [`std::ranges::views::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view)?

Comment: that works. I did try `view::iota` with the same error. but the second source listed it as `std::ranges::view::iota`, too. the first one listed `std::ranges::view::ints`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```cpp
auto ints = std::ranges::views::iota(0);
```

For some reason the video listed it as view::ints and the pdf source as view::iota, both of which are wrong.

Comment: `view` used to be the old name of `views` in range-v3, and `ints` is a view in range-v3 that generates `int`s I think.

Comment: how hot and new is this? I thought c++20 was done? why do they keep changing the names around?

Comment: Yeah, C++20 has been published, but people can make mistakes. It's just a cppcon talk, there are often minor mistakes in those, nothing to worry about.